# html5 validation regular expression

Tags: regex, html, validation

I only want alphanumeric, numbers, space, dash and underscore. I am using

```
[\w\s-_]*
```

But because I have allowed spaces, a space is allowed as input, in html5 how can i validate if only spaces are entered as input.

Also is there any regular expression checking integers for 1+.

Edit:

allowing integers from 1 to any positive integers {1, 2, 3, ...}

Comment: Please, elaborate on your last statement. 1+??

Comment: must your pattern match `1-2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following pattern that accepts a space only when surrounded by some other valid input characters as well. Please, note that `\w` already includes an `_` underscore.

```
[\w-]+(\s[\w-]+)*
```

To match all positive integers >= 1 use the regex

```
^(?!0)\d+
```

The above excludes `0`.

Comment: thnx this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to write a little javascript to find out if there are only spaces.
Get the input text then trim it and find if it's empty..

Answer (score 0):

```
this [link][1] will help you 
 OR try this 
   var str = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
   if (str.match(/^\s*$/)) {
    // nothing, or nothing but whitespace
   } else {
    // something
   }
```